# Hiding overflow on folder sidebar

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css, navbar, sidebar

I am struggling to make a basic CSS sidebar, and I can't figure out why. It seems to work on codepen examples, but I might miss something.

Here I have some code in an Astro component (html with tailwindcss)

```html
<body class="flex flex-col items-center max-w-full min-w-full min-h-screen lg:max-w-5xl lg:min-w-[1024px] overflow-hidden">
<header class="flex w-full h-20 overflow-hidden">

<div class="overflow-hidden">
    <div
        class="nav-menu absolute w-80 h-full overflow-hidden -right-80 bg-red-600 shadow-md -z-10 transition-all opacity-0">
        <p>Test</p>
    </div>
</div>

</header>
</body>
```

The div is set with a negative right value, which changes to 0 to unfold it. It is supposed to be hidden. On my screen, it is indeed hidden, but the overflow is not, and I can scroll to the right. I've put some `overflow: hidden` on my body, parent div, div and subdiv, still it doesn't work.

Additional infos :

- This div is hidden on desktop size, though i'm not sure if it changes anything
- I've tried removing the `w-full` class on the header, issue still occuring

Any help would be appreciated !

Comment: Please include a [mre] so we can see the issue occurring.

Comment: I've modified my answer to include everything up to the body, anything else is needed please let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

overflow-x controls how the content that overflows the horizontal axis.

```
<body class="flex flex-col items-center w-full min-w-full min-h-screen lg:max-w-5xl lg:min-w-[1024px] overflow-x-hidden">
  <header class="flex w-full h-20 overflow-hidden">
    <div class="relative">
      <div class="sidebar absolute w-80 h-full -right-80 bg-red-600 shadow-md opacity-0">
        <p>Test</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! It was the `relative` class that fixed it. I'll go document myself to find out why.

Comment: with the new `relative` property, the height of the sidebar is no longer 100%, any idea on how to fix that ?

Answer (score 1):

You can explicitly set the height so that it takes the full viewport height.

The only change needed is adding h-screen to `<div class="relative h-screen">`